How Microsoft control display breadcrumb max display items?
when I search breadcrumb component in breadcrumb. I found that when I resize the screen smaller, it's auto collapse item like this to fit screen
resize screen 1
resize screen 2
and auto display more item when it has enough space.
I have a question is how can Microsoft handle this one? Did they have any built-in function for that
Any help will be appreciated 

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

FluentUI is an open-source library, so you can see the source code of every component on their GitHub. This is the implementation of Breadcrumb in version 8.
